# why my java application creating multiple number of threads with name "JMX client heartbeat" which are consuming lot of CPU?

Tags: java

I have a java application which retrieves MBeans from remote systems. However it consumes lot of CPU crashed. When I ran jstack on the PID of thread that consumes lot of CPU, this is what I see:

```
JMX client heartbeat 148145" #229748 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fe3c2f46800 nid=0x56fc waiting on condition [0x00007fe1d267f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientCommunicatorAdmin$Checker.run(ClientCommunicatorAdmin.java:175)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"JMX client heartbeat 148039" #229615 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fe398317800 nid=0x564a waiting on condition [0x00007fe1d48a1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientCommunicatorAdmin$Checker.run(ClientCommunicatorAdmin.java:175)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"JMX client heartbeat 148036" #229612 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fe3903a4000 nid=0x5647 waiting on condition [0x00007fe1d49a2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientCommunicatorAdmin$Checker.run(ClientCommunicatorAdmin.java:175)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"JMX client heartbeat 147959" #229517 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fe3e09e3000 nid=0x55e7 waiting on condition [0x00007fe1d62bb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientCommunicatorAdmin$Checker.run(ClientCommunicatorAdmin.java:175)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"JMX client heartbeat 147854" #229385 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fe3f551e000 nid=0x5562 waiting on condition [0x00007fe1d83dc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientCommunicatorAdmin$Checker.run(ClientCommunicatorAdmin.java:175)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I don't know what this thread is and which part of my application creates it.

Comment: Are you closing all connections that you open?

Comment: @ivanivan I have checked and found a method where I have opened a JMXConnector object which I did not close.

Comment: I call this method every 30 seconds, where I need latest JMX data. Can you tell me what is the best way to handle JMXConnectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you aren't closing connections that you open, leading to the wait for timeout.

Best practices would be to explicitly close all connections as soon as the result is obtained.

Be aware that if you are `try`/`catch`-ing exceptions, etc. and not doing a lot the code to close the connection may not be reached, so  have a final check to see if any are open and close appropriately at the end of the method or whatever control structure you are in when the connection is opened.